# ajax success function return view on second click

Tags: jquery, ajax, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4, angularjs-factory

I am using ajax's post request in the angular's factory.... everything works fine except the ajax success function... you can see in success function i have to go on another page..(logout.html).. but the ajax's success function login me to second page after clicking login button two times,, i dont know what is problem any help please

my ajax call in angular factory

```
demoapp.factory("authser", function ($location) {
    return {
        login: function (credantials) {
            if (credantials.username != "jot") {
                alert("its ");
            }
            else {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/valued/newvalue",
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: { 'name': credantials.username, 'password': credantials.password },
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        console.log(data);
                        $location.path('/logout');

                    }
                });
            }
        },
        logout: function (data) {
console.log(data);

            $location.path('/hello');
        }
    }
})
```

my controller

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace angulardata.Controllers
{
    public class valuedController : Controller
    {
       // GET: /valued/
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult newvalue(string name, string password)
        {
            var res = new {Success="True",Message="Error MEssage" };
            return Json(res);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What is `the controller give me second page's view`? Please give a very detailed explanation.

Comment: How is this question different than [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21872015/ajax-requests-success-function-works-on-second-click) that you asked 18 mins earlier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using  `$.ajax` try to use `$http` angular service to call server that will trigger the angular digest cycle .

```
demoapp.factory("authser", function ($location,$http) {
```

//

```
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url:  "/valued/newvalue",
    responseType: "json",
   data: { 'name': credantials.username, 'password': credantials.password }
}).success(function (data) {
   console.log(data);
   $location.path('/logout');
});
```

Comment: is there any changes needed on the controller side

Comment: i tried but console says me that $http is not defined

Comment: does it require jquery.min.map ? on my console there is message that jquery.min.map not found...:(

Comment: This has nothing to do with `jquery.min.map`. It's all about angular. Any way that won't be an issue for this requirement . Is it working now ?

Comment: i am asking again does there is any changes required to controller code

Comment: What do you mean by not working , are u still getting same click issue or is it not working at all?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47816/discussion-between-jatt-net-and-jayantha)